# Heatsinks and Xeon E5 CPUs

Tags: cooling, heatsink, xeon

I've constructed a server that uses 2 Xeon E5-2620 CPUs and per Intel's recommendation I'm in the process of ordering a heatsink and I'm slightly concerned about thermal management. The case I'm using is well ventilated (the Coolermaster Cosmos II) but I have a few concerns regarding the adequacy of the heatsinks recommended by the MB manufacturer (Supermicro CPU HeatSink SNK-P0048PS). Can these heatsinks keep the Xeons within their normal temperature range? Shouldn't there be a fan on the heatsink?

Due to the low volume of literature on the topic I wasn't able to find anything conclusive.

Comment: I just built a server with two of these chips (very nice machine) and I'm using these (http://www.amazon.com/Intel-BXSTS200C-Thermal-Solution-STS200C/dp/B008Z29B2I). They're soooo loud. I've been trying to get my motherboard to throttle them down somewhat.. So far, no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rack servers don't usually have space for fans on the sinks, so I'm assuming that the heatsinks alone will do the trick...